# Attach a note to an email

Tags: gmail

I want to attach a little note on some conversations, for reference/summarization/etc.

[It is not yet built-in but Google is I think collecting enough votes for this feature.](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/OP_I3lADT8c)

[There's a third-party app but I don't want to have to trust/rely on anybody for this.](http://gmailnotes.appspot.com/3/static/site/html/gettingstarted.html)

Is there anything that could achieve the original purpose?

Case in point: I've an order placed and received tracking info via email, and I want to add a direct link to the tracking page to that email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Google's Task List, you could add the message as a Task and add notes to that.

"Add to Tasks" is under the "More" menu.

[image: "More" menu]

It's then added to your tasks, with a convenient link to open the original email message.

[image: Task list]

Then you can edit the task and add information to the "Notes" field.

[image: Edit task]

Answer (score 1):

I would just forward the message to myself, adding whatever notes I wanted in the forwarded message.

Answer (score -1):

Reply to the said conversation, add any notes you want, but do not (ever) hit send.

(This is my solution for the time being, unless someone has a better idea...?)